# SQL Code Error converting data type varchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

The following code encounters an error when executed in Microsoft Server Management Studion:

```
USE [DST]
GO

Select 
  CAST([Balance] as float)
FROM [RAW_XXX] 
WHERE ISNUMERIC(Balance) = 1
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 2
>   Error converting data type varchar to float.

I thought that the `ISNUMERIC` would exclude anything that can not be cast or converted.

It is a massive database in SQLServer 2012 so I am unsure how to find the data that is causing the error.

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT * FROM RAW_XXX WHERE ISNUMERIC(Balance) <>1` to find the data causing your error?

Comment: @daShier Yes. Removing those rows does not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TRY_CONVERT` to flush out the offending records:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [RAW_XXX] 
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, Balance) IS NULL;
```

The issue with your current logic is that something like `$123.45` would be true according to `ISNUMERIC`, but would fail when trying to cast as floating point.

By the way, if you wanted a more bare bones way of finding records not castable to float you could just rely on `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM [RAW_XXX]
WHERE Balance NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%' AND Balance NOT LIKE '%.%.%';
```

The first `LIKE` condition ensures that `Balance` consists only of numbers and decimal points, and the second condition ensures that at most one decimal point appears.  Checkout the demo below to see this working.

### Demo

Comment: `$405.27` would pass `ISNUMERIC` but not the `CAST`

Comment: @Gerhard I was going to comment something to this effect.